# Ubuntu 12.10 strange screen

Tags: ubuntu

I've installed Ubuntu 12.10 desktop as a virtual machine on my VMware ESXi server. And i have no idea why the screen looks like this. And i can't find anything by googeling. Anyone?

[image: Resolution error?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [here](https://blogs.vmware.com/guestosguide/guest-os/linux/ubuntu) and [here](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?deviceCategory=software&testConfig=16) you can see that you need esxi version 5.1

Not sure why I cannot comment on your question but do you have such version or an older ones?

Comment: that's strange :P (the comment bit) ... My ESXi version is 4.0.0 which must be the problem. thanks @alex88 :)

Comment: I think that's due my low reputation. Your welcome ;)